# Facebook comments not showing for all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, social-networking

I am using the new facebook comments plugin. I've been able to integrate it to by site and for the most part works as expected. My issue is that for some users, the comments left by others are not visible. I used the facebook lint tool to make sure my appId is picked up property, and it is.

Has anyone else observed such behaviour?

Comment: Yes, we've noticed that behavior during testing the past few days. Some users' comments only display when that user is logged into their FB account. I was trying to look into the Comments Moderation Settings, but that is stuck on Loading... in all browsers right now.

Comment: I am currently having the same problem.  I wonder if it has anything to do with the fb: meta tags?